# Counting number of duplicates using Arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates, counting

I have a zip code file which has the zip code in the format
Zipcode,city,county

```
90001,Los Angeles,Los Angeles
90002,Los Angeles,Los Angeles
90003,Los Angeles,Los Angeles
90004,Los Angeles,Los Angeles
90005,Los Angeles,Los Angeles
```

I have created a list which holds the objects of `Zipcode` class. What I'm trying is to count the number of zipcodes in a county and print it. Something like this:

```
Los Angeles: 525
San Diego: 189
Orange: 149
```

etc.

This is the code I've tried so far:

```
void printInfo() {
        int count=0;
        Collections.sort(zipcodes);    //natural order of county
        for (int i = 0; i < zipcodes.size()-1;i++)
        {
            for (int j = i+1; j < zipcodes.size(); j++)
            {
                if (zipcodes.get(i).county.equals(zipcodes.get(j).county)) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            state.add(new County(zipcodes.get(i).county,count));
        }


        Collections.sort(state);
        for (County z: state) {
            System.out.println("County: " + z.county + " " + "Count: " + z.count );     
        }
}
```

The output I'm getting looks like:
    Los Angeles: 148
    Orange: 148
    San Diego: 148
    Los Angeles: 149
    San Diego: 149
    .....
    Los Angeles: 188
    San Diego: 188
    .....
    Los Angeles: 524

Need help. Not sure what I'm doing wrong in this loop.

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: I'm not getting the correct output. For ex:
County: Los Angeles Count: 524
County: Los Angeles Count: 1047
County: Los Angeles Count: 1569
County: Los Angeles Count: 2090
County: Los Angeles Count: 2610
County: Los Angeles Count: 3129
County: Los Angeles Count: 3647
I'm getting differ LA count instead of one Los Angeles count.

Comment: For one thing, you're not resetting `count` inside the `i` loop.

Comment: "I'm not getting the correct output" is not an actionable description of a problem. What *is* the correct output, what are you getting instead?

Comment: It isn't your problem, but you should also have an `else` with a `break` if they're sorted by county, since as soon as one doesn't match none of the rest will.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/, e.g. a **web search** for [`java count frequency`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+count+frequency)

Comment: You could count them in one line using a stream that produces a map, or you could structure your classes to have sets of their child classes, ie State has a Set of County, and County has a Set of zipcodes, then the size of the Set would automatically give you your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MSG
Much simpler solution (assuming that zipCodes is a List < ZipCode > )

```
    Map<String, Long> processed = zipCodes.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ZipCode::getCounty, Collectors.counting()
        )                        
    );

    processed.entrySet().stream().forEach(zipCode -> System.out.println(zipCode));
```

Answer (score 0):

just put count=0; before second loop as below:

```
  count = 0;
  for (int j = i+1; j < zipcodes.size(); j++)
     ......
```